# Is it possible to encrypt something using literally only a public key?

Tags: public-key

Most basic explanations of asymmetric encryption proceed as follows:

Bob wants to send encrypted message to Alice.  Bob and Alice each generate public/private key pairs.  Bob gets Alice's public key and "encrypts the message".

I have always assumed that Bob used Alice's public key *and* his own private key to encrypt the message.  However, maybe he only used Alice's public key with no other input.  Which is correct?

Even if Bob didn't use his own private key, was an ephemeral key generated to stand in for Bob's private key?

Is it possible to use Alice's key with no other input than the message being encrypted?  If only Alice's public key is used, then what cypher(s) is being used to encrypt?

EDIT: 2019-12-10 Clarification

It seemed implicit to me, but I should clarify that the goal is to encrypt using  *only* Alice's public key in such a way that it can *only* be decrypted with her private key.  In other words, *not* symmetric encryption with an exposed public key.

Comment: I can simply say this is too broad. Get Alice's key and send a message to her. That is it!. If Alice wants to know the sender than Bob must sign the message.

Comment: I guess this is something the experts assume is understood, but I have spent several hours trying to find a reliable statement of this fact and found the information contradictory and unclear.

Comment: Your title: "yes". You don't "encrypt" with the private key. Maybe try and get a copy of A Very Short Introduction to Cryptography. It's old (2002) but all of the concepts are still up to date. Then read Crypto101.io.

Comment: I added a clarification because it seems like my efforts to keep the title short, muddied my question.  As the first line indicates I am referring to *asymmetric encryption* and a solution that uses Alice's public key as a symmetric key would be invalid.  The consensus of answers to my question are "yes", however I still suspect the answer is no.  I have not heard of an algorithm that can do this without creating an ephemeral private key to complete the encryption.  Obviously, Alice cannot authenticate the "sender" but that is beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: @jedatu: be assured that the answer is a clear yes. For efficiency reasons, most practical encryption-only applications (e.g. GPG/OpenPGP in asymetric encryption mode without signature) internally use symmetric cryptography in addition to asymmetric cryptography. But this can be avoided, and some systems in wide use for short messages, including [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=23), use no symmetric crypto (counting hashes but not TRNGs as symmetric crypto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have always assumed that Bob used Alice's public key and his own private key to encrypt the message. However, maybe he only used Alice's public key with no other input. Which is correct?

In a simplified scenario we can say that Bob only uses Alice's public key to encrypt the message. When you want to ensure *confidentiality* you basically want that only Alice is able to read the message Bob is sending.

However, there are cases where Bob also wants to protect the message's integrity and show he's the one sending this message. Towards that goal, Bob will process the message with his own private key. This is called *signature*.

That is, how can Alice be sure that the message really comes from Bob or someone else trying to impersonating him? In order to solve this issue, Bob can *sign* the message with his private key and Alice can verify the signature using Bob's public key. In this way, we achieved also *authentication*, that is we made sure that message really came from Bob.

Again, this is a simplified scenario, because you would need a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) in order to complete the picture and ensure that public/private key pair really belongs to Bob.

> Even if Bob didn't use his own private key, was an ephemeral key generated to stand in for Bob's private key?

Public key encryption is slow. Therefore the typical encryption schema requires to generate and ephemeral symmetric key to be used to encrypt messages exchanged between Alice and Bob. This is also referred as *session key*, as it is discarded as soon as the communication session is over.

> Is it possible to use Alice's key with no other input than the message being encrypted? If only Alice's public key is used, then what cypher(s) is being used to encrypt?

In theory, yes, you can only use Alice's public key to encrypt the message. RSA and DH are prominent asymmetric encryption algorithms. However, they are usually combined with other algorithms to implement different properties. E.g. AES for symmetric encryption and SHA for hashing.

Comment: So, to be clear, adding Bob's signature or an ephemeral symmetric key is optional.  Also, I am surprised DH would work in this case because I thought DH was negotiating a shared secret between two parties.

Comment: Today, they are not really optional. Look how TLS works [here](https://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/tls/basics/), it is a good reference to see how all these concepts come together to implement a secure connection.

Comment: I think that is partly the issue in that most guides are referring to applied cryptography which may or may not have other concerns. I have a specific use case where I want to encrypt a payload using a public key and nothing else. My assumption had always been that other elements were necessary for asymmetric encryption, but it sounds like they only serve as secondary benefits.

Comment: I don't want to be misinterpreted. Other elements, like generation of ephemeral key, PKI, signature and hashing solve other **problems**, which are not exactly secondary when it comes to secure a communication. 
About your specific use case, I would suggest to reason on that and perhaps ask another question here with more focus on your use case's limitations and requirements.

Comment: You wrote _there are cases where also Bob wants to "encrypt" the message with his own private key_. Despite the quotes, this is a dangerous slope. It suggests that producing a signature is similar to encryption except for using a different key, which is wrong in general, and not even correct for proper use of RSA. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76234/555). What about: _there are cases where Bob also wants to protect the message's integrity and show he's the one sending this message. Towards that goal, Bob will process the message with his own private key_.

Comment: I like your suggestion, can you edit my answer to incorporate that?

Answer (score 1):

> I have always assumed that Bob used Alice's public key and his own private key to encrypt the message. However, maybe he only used Alice's public key with no other input. Which is correct?

Depends on the crypto scheme. If you use RSA schemes (e.g. those defined in the PKCS#1 standards using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP) for encryption then you only need a *trusted* public key for encryption and a private key for decryption.

> Even if Bob didn't use his own private key, was an ephemeral key generated to stand in for Bob's private key?

However, some crypto systems such as those for Elliptic Curves do not have a direct way of encrypting data (of any practical size). In that case often a scheme such as (EC)IES is used. That's basically Diffie-Hellman key agreement, which is based one two key pairs. In that case Bob needs his own (ephemeral) key pair.

> Is it possible to use Alice's key with no other input than the message being encrypted? If only Alice's public key is used, then what cypher(s) is being used to encrypt?

Any cipher that allows enough data to be encrypted. However, generally asymmetric encryption is inefficient, both when it comes to expanding the ciphertext size and with regards to computation requirements. So in that case ciphers such as RSA & AES are commonly combined into a hybrid cryptosystem.

---

Generally you encrypt to achieve confidentiality. If message integrity & authenticity is also required - it almost always is when it comes to communication protocols - then you also need to sign the data. In that case Bob requires a private key to create the signature (and Alice needs to trust the corresponding public key).

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Interestingly, it was while looking at the code for an ECIES library that I began wondering about this.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wrote the answer, I saw you talk about ephemeral keys and thought that the IES part was missing from the other answer.